# Max addresses that can be cleared from an array before breaking gas

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, gas, arrays, out-of-gas

I've been trying to properly test this for about two days with issues here and there. I got to 240, and it errored out bc of Gas when i attempted to clear.. Good thats what i wanted to see..but I have been trying to test a number lower, and now just having issues with ganache. I have my plan in place once I figure out the max number of arrays I can have. Does anybody know this number? How I can figure out this number in an easier way than manually running mass amounts of tx's?

The first time through it worked with ganache and remix, and did not need to use metamask.. Now Ganache crashes out after like 3 tx's for some reason unless I use metamask. So with metamask it is much more time-consuming to test..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the addresses are included within the smart contract, you could call [`delete`](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=clear#delete) on them. If they are included within an array, that could be significantly cheaper.